# Object cannot be cast as Parcelable

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to pass an object (News) through an intent but I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.site.myapplication.model.News cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
```

This is my implementation of the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(viewGroup.getContext(), ViewNewsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ViewNewsActivity.EXTRA_NEWS, (Parcelable) currentNews);
viewGroup.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this? I'm using Android Studio for implementing by the way.

Comment: Your news class must implement **Parcelable**

Comment: you have implement Parcelable in News class

Comment: Does your News class, in fact, implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: It doesn't! I think that is what's missing. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned it the comments above, the News class must implement Parcelable. Also, there is no need to typecast it once the News class implements Parcelable.